# SelectList not selecting a default value from List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, selectlist

I am starting to get very annoyed with this, but no matter what, I am not able to get `SelectedValue` to work for a `SelectList`.

This is my code:

```
List<string> PickupTimeList = EntityLogic.PopulateTimeSlots(vm.DateMileage.PickupDate,
    vm.DateMileage.PickupDate.AddHours(-2), vm.DateMileage.PickupDate.AddHours(2).AddMinutes(15));

ViewBag.PickupTimeList = new SelectList(PickupTimeList, "11:00 PM");
```

I don't have a Text/Key value here because Text/Key will also be a string and same thing. Anyway, by this code, it's still not selecting "11:00 PM" as the default item.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: are you sure you have "11:00 PM" in the list?

Comment: 11:00 PM is just an example but yes, I do have it in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var pickupTimeList = EntityLogic.PopulateTimeSlots(
    vm.DateMileage.PickupDate,
    vm.DateMileage.PickupDate.AddHours(-2), 
    vm.DateMileage.PickupDate.AddHours(2).AddMinutes(15)
)
.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x,
    Text = x,
});

ViewBag.PickupTimeList = new SelectList(PickupTimeList, "Value", "Text", "11:00 PM");
```

Comment: This is the Razor Engine code: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PickupTime, (SelectList)ViewBag.PickupTimeList)

Comment: What's the value of the `PickupTime` property on your view model? Make sure that it is a string with value `11:00 PM`. Since your DropDOwn is bound to this model property, it's value is taken into account when determining the selected option and not the value you passed in the `SelectList` constructor. So you'd rather set this property in your controller action to the desired value: `model.PickupTime = "11:00 PM";`.

Comment: It worked!! All I did was this: ViewBag.PickupTimeList = new SelectList(PickupTimeList); I selected the default value by editing the model.PickupTime, rather than the selectlist. I've never seen something like this before but it did work now. I'll accept this answer, maybe you want to update this detail in your answer for someone who will be viewing this in the future. :P